# Hide a component and display another component within a component page - react js

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a application in which I have created three components.js page as below.

one.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TwoComponent from 'two.component';
import ThreeComponent from 'three.component';
export default class OneComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 Hi!
                 <TwoComponent />
                 <ThreeComponent />
             <>
        )
    }
}
```

two.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class TwoComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 Hi Two Component!
             </>
        )
    }
}
```

three.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class ThreeComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 Hi Three Component!
             </>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, I want only the component  has to be displayed and the other  has to be hided.

With in two.component.js I have a button. On clicking the button, I need to show three.component.js and the two.component.js has to be hided.

Modified the above files as below.

one.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TwoComponent from 'two.component';
import ThreeComponent from 'three.component';
export default class OneComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 Hi!
                 { 
                   this.state.count === 2 ?
                     <TwoComponent twoButtonClicked={this.props.triggerButtonClick} />
                     :
                     <ThreeComponent />
                 }
             <>
        )
    }
    
    triggerButtonClick(){ 
        this.setState({ count: 2 }); 
    }
}
```

two.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class TwoComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 <input type="button" onClick={this.twoButtonClicked} />
             </>
        )
    }
}
```

Here, the function triggerButtonClick is not triggering.

Kindly help me to display the components based on condition from within one of the component. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**First, fix Syntax Errors in your code.**

Then follow best practices when your coding. For example, we always add the `render` method at the end of the component.

Fixes that made to your code, to work as expected mentioned below.

**one.component.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TwoComponent from './two.component';
import ThreeComponent from './three.component'; // Fix 7 - Update component import statements with './'

export default class OneComponent extends Component {
    state = {
       count: 2, // Fix 2 - According to your requirement this should be 2.
    }; // Fix 1 - Define the state property  

    triggerButtonClick = () => { 
        this.setState({ count: 1 }); // Fix 4 - When consider your requirement this should be other than 2.
    } // Fix 3 - Use an arrow function here to define the method.

    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 Hi!
                 { 
                   this.state.count === 2 ?
                     <TwoComponent twoButtonClicked={this.triggerButtonClick} />
                     :
                     <ThreeComponent />
                 }
                 {/* Fix 5 - Remove this.props.triggerButtonClick and add this.triggerButtonClick */}
             <>
        )
    }
}
```

**two.component.js:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class TwoComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 <input type="button" onClick={this.props.twoButtonClicked} />
                 {/* Fix 6 - Get twoButtonClicked from the props object. */}
             </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting the best practices and the fix mentioned. I have modified my code but still the function is not calling. this.props.twoButtonClicked is not calling the function.

Comment: I update my post with a 7th fix. When you import the same directory files always add './'. Try that

Answer (score 0):

In component `two.component.js`, you are accessing `twoButtonClicked` method passed as prop like `this.twoButtonClicked` but you should be accessing it like `this.props.twoButtonClicked`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class TwoComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <>
                 <input type="button" onClick={this.props.twoButtonClicked} />
             </>
        )
    }
}
```

I have updated your code and added a snippet below, please check

```js
const { Component, Fragment } = React;

class TwoComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.props.twoButtonClicked} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ThreeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Fragment>Hi Three Component!</Fragment>;
  }
}

class OneComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //initialised count as `2` so as to display component two by default 
      count: 2
    };
  }

  //Converted to an arrow function in order to use this method
  //like `this.triggerButtonClick` otherwise we should bind this 
  //method in the constructor
  triggerButtonClick = () => {
    //Updating the count to `3` so as to hide component two.
    this.setState({ count: 3 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        Hi!
        {this.state.count === 2 ? (
          <TwoComponent twoButtonClicked={this.triggerButtonClick} />
        ) : (
          <ThreeComponent />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<OneComponent />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Modified and still the function not called..

Comment: I have provided the runnable snippet, can you check that once if it's fitting in your requirement.

Comment: The code snippet worked like charm and this is the exact output I want. But When I implemented this, I couldn't get the function to be called. I am having separate export class for each component and in separate file. Would that cause any issues in calling the function? and the component have no parent, child relation too..

Comment: I think the function is not getting called because you are neither binding `twoButtonClicked` in `OneComponent` component nor defined it as an arrow function.
I have created a sandbox as per your component structure, please check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-hide-two-three-e02hn?file=/src/App.js)